# How to convert a user-defined named type/struct to it's anonymous type

Tags: go

## The original question

I have the following Go code. I would like to handle `Foo` a struct or `Bar` a type as a string. With "handle" I mean that I would like to convert/cast/whatever it's underlaying value to the (real) type `string`. I have a workaround, but I find it unintuitive in the case of a struct.

Going for a Type (instead of a struct) seems the better approach. I don't need to maintain any state, nor do I have any need for "inheriting" type specific functionality, so in my case it should work. However a call to `type.String()` causes stack recursion. I'm mostly curious if I'm not missing something (obvious).

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    string
}

func (f *Foo) String() string {
    return f.string
}


type Bar string

func (b *Bar) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s", b) // Cannot use: return string(b) here.
}

func main() {
    a := Foo{"a"}
    var b Bar
    b = "b"

    fmt.Printf("A is: %s\n", a) // Doesn't call a.String() ?
    //fmt.Printf("A is: %s\n", string(a)) // Doesn't work
    fmt.Printf("A is: %s\n", a.string)   // workaround A
    fmt.Printf("A is: %s\n", a.String()) // workaround B, required if I want to use it in a different package

    fmt.Printf("B is: %s\n", b) // Calls b.String()
    fmt.Printf("B is: %s\n", string(b))
    //fmt.Printf("B is: %s\n", b.String()) // Causes a stack overflow
}
```

Output:

```
A is: {a}
A is: a
A is: a
B is: b
B is: b
```

Code on Go's Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/zgrKao4cxa
The behaviour is from Go version 1.5.2

## Answers

The following are short examples based on the answers of my original questions. Also, the following post helped in understanding and reasoning of the subject: [Value receiver vs. Pointer receiver in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775376/value-receiver-vs-pointer-receiver-in-golang)

In case of a type, the following works:

```
type MyString string

func (b MyString) String() string {
    return string(b)
}
```

Go's Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/H12bteAk8D

In case of a struct, the following works:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyString struct {
    string
    someState int
}

func (m MyString) String() string {
    return string(m.string)
}

func main() {
    // The verbose version: 
    //var a MyString = MyString{string: "a", someState: 1}

    a := MyString{"a", 1}

    fmt.Printf("A is: %s\n", a)
    fmt.Printf("A is: %s\n", a.String())
}
```

Go's Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/GEKeY4rmB8

Comment: b's String() function can use `return string(*b)`, didn't need to sprintf the value.  just needed to match the return type of of the function

Comment: Ah, you're right. I can't believe I missed that. I think I was thrown off by the error message `cannot convert b (type *Bar) to type string`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Dynom Please don't add answers to your question. If you've got some interesting info to share, add your own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a pointer receivers for your `String` methods, but you are working with values, not pointers to them, so it wouldn't apply. You need to switch to pointers or change `String` methods signatures:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    string
}

func (f Foo) String() string {
    return "My " + f.string
}

type Bar string

func (b Bar) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("My %s", string(b))
}

func main() {
    a := Foo{"a"}
    var b Bar = "b"

    fmt.Printf("A is: %s\n", a)
    fmt.Printf("B is: %s\n", b)
}
```

Please, be careful with [receivers type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775376/value-receiver-vs-pointer-receiver-in-golang):

> The rule about pointers vs. values for receivers is that value methods
>   can be invoked on pointers and values, but pointer methods can only be
>   invoked on pointers

Oh, and one more thing. `fmt.Sprintf("%s", b)` will call `String` method if it's defined. So, you'll get a recursion.

Comment: Actually, that makes a lot of sense.  But how come dereferencing in the method doesn't work? I've tried this, but that doesn't work:

    func (f *Foo) String() string {
        return (*f).string
    }

Comment: When you pass printf a you are passing it the value a.  Change it to &a (pointer to a) and your String() func will get called (from line 24 in your play example).  But it's notmally weird to pass around pointers to strings, so this answer makes more sense

Comment: @Dynom, "The rule about pointers vs. values for receivers is that value methods can be invoked on pointers and values, but pointer methods can only be invoked on pointers"

Comment: Allright, that helped. Thanks for the explanations!