# Using reflection SetString

Tags: string, go, reflection, struct

I have a struct like this one:

```
type ProductionInfo struct {
    StructA []Entry
}

type Entry struct {
    Field1 string
    Field2 int
}
```

I would like to change the value of `Field1` using reflection but the reflect object returned always `CanSet() = false`. What can I do? See playground example.

https://play.golang.org/p/eM_KHC3kQ5

Here is the code:

```
func SetField(source interface{}, fieldName string, fieldValue string) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(source)
    tt := reflect.TypeOf(source)

    for k := 0; k < tt.NumField(); k++ {
        fieldValue := reflect.ValueOf(v.Field(k))

        fmt.Println(fieldValue.CanSet())
        if fieldValue.CanSet() {
            fieldValue.SetString(fieldValue.String())
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    source := ProductionInfo{}
    source.StructA = append(source.StructA, Entry{Field1: "A", Field2: 2})

    SetField(source, "Field1", "NEW_VALUE")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Multiple errors. Let's iterate over them.

First, you pass a value of `ProductionInfo` and not a value of `Entry` whose field you want to modify, so first change it to:

```
SetField(source.StructA[0], "Field1", "NEW_VALUE")
```

Next, you are passing a (non-pointer) value. You can't modify the fields of a non-pointer struct with reflection, because that would only modify a copy which would be discarded. In order to avoid this (and further confusion), this is not allowed (`CanSet()` returns `false`). So you have to pass a pointer to the struct:

```
SetField(&source.StructA[0], "Field1", "NEW_VALUE")
```

Now inside `SetField()` the `reflect.ValueOf(source)` will describe the passed pointer. You may use [`Value.Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem) to navigate to the [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) of the pointed object (the struct value):

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(source).Elem()
```

And now it works. Modified code:

```
func SetField(source interface{}, fieldName string, fieldValue string) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(source).Elem()

    fmt.Println(v.FieldByName(fieldName).CanSet())

    if v.FieldByName(fieldName).CanSet() {
        v.FieldByName(fieldName).SetString(fieldValue)
    }
}

func main() {
    source := ProductionInfo{}
    source.StructA = append(source.StructA, Entry{Field1: "A", Field2: 2})

    fmt.Println("Before: ", source.StructA[0])
    SetField(&source.StructA[0], "Field1", "NEW_VALUE")
    fmt.Println("After: ", source.StructA[0])
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/L-Uvxdg8sy)):

```
Before:  {A 2}
true
After:  {NEW_VALUE 2}
```

Comment: Thank you for tips Icza. I know there was errors during assegnation because i tried to create "dummy" code for example and I did it in a very short time :) . BTW I got where my erorrs were. Thank you