# How to pass by address to function that takes interface

Tags: pointers, go, types, interface, type-assertion

I have a `Character` interface defined like:

```
type Character interface {
    SomeFunction()
}
```

And a `Player` struct defined like:

```
type Player struct{}

func (r *Player) SomeFunction() { }
// Some fields and other functions....
```

Suppose I have a function defined as

```
func TakeInterface(characterValue Character) {
     // Do something
}
```

The catch is, I want to pass in `characterValue` as a `Player` by **address** so that changes made to it will be made to the `Player` the caller passed in. In Java and C++, this is easy, but I can't seem to figure it out in Golang. I've tried something like,

```
func TakeInterface(characterValue &Character) {
    // Do something that changes characterValue
}
```

and then passing in a `Player` pointer, but then I get the error `*Character.Character is pointer to interface, not interface` when I try to pass in an address.

How do I go about passing a `Player` by address to a function that takes a `Character`/`Character` pointer? I've been looking around but with no success. Thanks!

Comment: Make SomeFuncion take a pointer reciever?

Comment: @Volker in my implementation, SomeFunction() was already taking a pointer receiver, updated the question accordingly, thanks for noticing.

Comment: Take the address of a Player and pass it to TakeInterface.   See https://play.golang.org/p/oZKuFC0z1l .

Comment: "How do I go about passing a Player by address to a function that takes a Character/Character pointer?" You simply *do* *not* *do* *this*! You never (except you need to and you do not!) pass pointers to interfaces. You pass values to interfaces. This is possible if the  type implements the interface. Some type implement interfaces only for pointer receivers.

Comment: @Volker but Player isn't an interface. What they're describing is completely normal: passing a pointer to an object to a function that takes an interface that the object satisfies.

Comment: I'm not talking about Player. You asked about "a Character/Character pointer" and that is _wrong_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tested your code? I'm guessing no, because it works the way you expect it to work. Just pass a pointer to a player when calling the function.

```
func main() {
    p := new(Player)
    TakeInterface(p)
}
```

Or

```
func main() {
    p := Player{0}
    TakeInterface(&p)
}
```

In go you can use a type or a pointer to a type as an argument to a function that takes an interface because both satisfy the interface. You can do both:

```
    var p1 Player
    p1.SomeFunction()
    var p2 *Player
    p2.SomeFunction()
```

You should do the tour of go: https://tour.golang.org/methods/10

Here is the whole code: https://play.golang.org/p/iQIChLCziG

Comment: To answer your question, I tested my code but it didn't occur to me that you could pass a value or a pointer to a function that takes an interface value. I kept trying to pass a player pointer to a function taking a character pointer. I looked around but didn't find an answer like this, my bad. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370277/type-is-pointer-to-interface-not-interface-confusion/44372954#44372954) for a bit more details on pointers versus values and interfaces and how that all functions.