# New function in interface type not working

Tags: go, struct, interface

If I have an interface type like:

```
type Message interface {
  New() *Message
  Get() string
}
```

and a structure like this:

```
type Entity struct {}
func (e *Entity) New() *Entity {
  return e
}
func (e Entiy) Get() string {
  return "hi"
}
```

Entity will not be a Message type unless I remove the `New() *Message`.
Can someone explain to me why that is not working and/or where my issue is?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/tE8ao7eyS0e

Comment: @dm03514 thanks! I guess it has to work this way. I maybe misunderstood the way how interfaces are working

Comment: The whole pointer to an interface is really confusing, i'm trying to think how to explain it but am not even familiar with what technically is going on under the hood.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370277/type-is-pointer-to-interface-not-interface-confusion

has a good explanation, and a couple of really good links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `Entity` to fulfill your interface it must comply strictly with the interface definition:

Trying to print an entity using

```
func msg(m Message) {
  fmt.Println(m.Get())
}
```

shows:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    e := &Entity{}
    e2 := e.New()
    msg(e2)
}
prog.go:28:5: cannot use e2 (type *Entity) as type Message in argument to msg:
    *Entity does not implement Message (wrong type for New method)
        have New() *Entity
        want New() *Message
```

Updating `Entity.New()` to return a pointer to a `Message` interface now shows:

```
type Message interface {
  New() *Message
  Get() string
}

type Entity struct {}
func (e *Entity) New() *Message {
  return e

prog.go:14:3: cannot use e (type *Entity) as type *Message in return argument:
    *Message is pointer to interface, not interface
prog.go:28:5: cannot use e2 (type *Message) as type Message in argument to msg:
    *Message is pointer to interface, not interface
```

More about this can be read:

["<type> is pointer to interface, not interface" confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370277/type-is-pointer-to-interface-not-interface-confusion)

Now updating your methods to return an interface instead of a pointer to an interface yields:

```
type Message interface {
  New() Message
  Get() string
}

type Entity struct {}
func (e *Entity) New() Message {
  return e
}
func (e Entity) Get() string {
  return "hi"
}

func msg(m Message) {
  fmt.Println(m.Get())
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    e := &Entity{}
    e2 := e.New()
    msg(e2)
}

Hello, playground
hi
```