# Why is io.EOF not a constant?

Tags: go, constants

I was rather surprised that [`io.EOF`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/io/io.go#L38) is *not* declared a constant, but an exported variable. Although not a big deal, this subjects it to unintended reassignment. Why not declare it a constant? Is this because [constants in Go are rather unusual](https://blog.golang.org/constants)?

Comment: The decision was that predeclared errors should be singletons, so that comparing different instances of errors would not be unexpectedly equal.

Comment: SO is weird. I can't correct my previous comment (since, apparently, it is more than 2 hours old -- deleting that comment is not an option). Here's the [correct link](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/07/constant-errors) demonstrating that others make this observation too (`Could we change the definition of io.EOF to be a constant?`), @Flimzy.

Comment: That's because then you'll have to delete your comment which would otherwise be rendered _dangling_ (you should delete your comment and then I can delete my first comment). By the way, do you know the answer to my question?

Comment: Also this answer gives some insight: [Custom errors in golang and pointer receivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333428/custom-errors-in-golang-and-pointer-receivers/50333850#50333850) (constants can't be pointers).

Comment: Dangling comments are not really a concern. Comments are always considered ephemeral.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you say constants are "unusual". Are you referring to the way Go handles untyped constants?

Comment: @icza thanks! From [the Go Blog](https://blog.golang.org/constants): "But in Go, a constant is just a simple, unchanging value, and from here on we're talking only about Go." -- My question: is it _not_ possible to have this restriction (unchanging value) and still make `io.EOF` a constant (because it _feels_ and _behaves_ like one)?

Comment: Of course it’s possible, but the language wasn’t designed that way. What real world benefit would this have for the added complication to the spec and implementation? Users can always write bad code and do bad things; someone reassigning `io.EOF` just isn’t considered a significant issue.

Comment: @JimB, thanks. I agree, this question perhaps solicits answers from the language designers. The [link](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/07/constant-errors) provides some ideas about implementation without changing the spec at all. The pivotal question is: Should a _value_ of a type other than basic types be allowed to be a constant?

Comment: The example in that post demonstrates why they chose to implement `errors.New` the way they did, specifically so that different instances don’t compare as equal.