# How to returned an error as a value instead of reference

Tags: go

I am creating a custom error and used it as a function return:

```
type MyError struct {
    Name string
}

func (me *MyError) Error() string {

    return me.Name + " is my error"
}
```

Function that returns the custom error:

```
func (anyStruct *AnyStruct) Validate() error {
    // if Any verification {

        return &MyError{Name: "MyError"}

    //}
}
```

Why can't I return as a value instead of a reference? If I try to return as a value:

`return MyError{Name: "MyError"}`

The editor's linter complains about an error:

> cannot use (MyError literal) (value of type MyError) as error value in return statement: missing method Error

Also, I am confused by the fact that a reference is being returned but the function signature does not inform that a pointer will be returned:

`func (anyStruct *AnyStruct) Validate() error {` instead of `func (anyStruct *AnyStruct) Validate() *error {`

Comment: For why the linter wants you to use a pointer, check out the most voted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333428/custom-errors-in-golang-and-pointer-receivers). For why the return type is `error` and not `*error`, that is because `error` is an `interface` (which you can find in the `builtin` package if you'd like to see it).

Comment: @phonaputer

_"""For why the return type is error and not *error, that is because error is an interface (which you can find in the builtin package if you'd like to see it)"""_

Does it mean that whenever a function's return type is an interface I don't need the pointer flag ("*"), even if the return is a reference?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You might want to read up on how interfaces work in Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`error` is an interface type so a type that can be used as an error must implement the `Error()` method.  The type in your code that implements `Error()` is `*MyError` (ie pointer to MyError).  When `Validate()` returns the return value is implicitly converted to an error - only `*MyError` (and not `MyError`) can be converted to an `error`.

To do what you want you should instead have `MyError` implement `Error()`.

```
func (me MyError) Error() string {
    return me.Name + " is my error"
}
```

Note that whatever type you return if the function returns an `error` the return value will be stored in an interface (remember `error` is an interface type).  And like most types a pointer can be stored in an interface.  Also be careful using the word "reference" type - in Go that usually refers to types (interface, map, etc) that internally contain pointers though I guess it would also includes pointers.