# Go - errors.As failing to unwrap custom error type

Tags: go, error-handling

I'm trying to use the Go stdlib package [errors](https://pkg.go.dev/errors) to unwrap a custom error type using `errors.As`, however it seems as though the check is failing and I cannot extract the underlying error.

I've extracted a minimal reproducible example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type myError struct {
    err error
}

func (m myError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("my error: %s", m.err)
}

func retError() error {
    return &myError{errors.New("wrapped")}
}

func main() {
    var m myError
    if err := retError(); errors.As(err, &m) {
        fmt.Println("unwrapped", m.err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/I7BNk4-rDIB - the example on the Go playground. If launched, it will print "my error: wrapped" instead of the expected "unwrapped wrapped".

The example from the `errors.As` documentation works, and I can't seem to understand what am I doing incorrectly - I'm passing a `*myError` to `errors.As`, which seems to be correct (since passing a `myError` raises a panic: `target must be a non-nil pointer`, which is expected).

Comment: `&myError` is not assignable to `myError`, see the `pathError` declaration in the [`As` example](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#example-As) you linked

Comment: It's also probably a good idea to use a pointer receiver for errors and fix your `pathError`, rather than continue using a struct value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50333850/32880

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
func retError() error {
    return &myError{errors.New("wrapped")}
}
```

Do:

```
func retError() error {
    return myError{errors.New("wrapped")}
}
```