# Why can't embedded types be passed as pointers

Tags: go

Can someone explain why this doesn't work? It works if `DoMove` takes a struct instead of a pointer.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Vehicle interface {
    Move()
}

type Car interface {
    Vehicle
    Wheels() int
}

type car struct {}

func (f car) Move() { fmt.Println("Moving...") }
func (f car) Colour() int { return 4 }

func DoMove(v *Vehicle) {
    v.Move()
}

func main() {
    f := car{}
    DoMove(&f)

}
```

Comment: Never use pointer to interface.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370277/type-is-pointer-to-interface-not-interface-confusion

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. In your `DoMove()` function, the variable is of `*Vehicle` type (pointer to the `Vehicle` interface). The pointer has no method `Move` at all.

The usual practice is to use the interface as function argument, but pass in pointer to struct (and make sure the pointer implements the interface). Example,

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Vehicle interface {
    Move()
}

type Car interface {
    Vehicle
    Wheels() int
}

type car struct {
        status string
}

func (f *car) Move() {
        fmt.Println("Moving...")
        f.status = "Moved"
}
func (f car) Status() string {
        return f.status
}

func DoMove(v Vehicle) {
    v.Move()
}

func main() {
    f := car{status: "Still"}
    DoMove(&f)
    fmt.Println(f.Status())
}
```

Output:

```
Moving...
Moved
```

The *car content is indeed changed.