# Function throws error when passing a pointer to interface?

Tags: go

So this is what I ran into, and I can't understand why the error:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// define a basic interface
type I interface {
    get_name() string
}

// define a struct that implements the "I" interface
type Foo struct {
    Name string
}

func (f *Foo) get_name() string {
    return f.Name
}

// define two print functions:
// the first function accepts *I. this throws the error
// changing from *I to I solves the problem
func print_item1(item *I) {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", item.get_name())
}

// the second function accepts *Foo. works well
func print_item2(item *Foo) {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", item.get_name())
}

func main() {
    print_item1(&Foo{"X"})
    print_item2(&Foo{"Y"})
}
```

Two identical functions accept a single argument: a pointer to either the interface, or the struct that implements it.
The first one that accepts the pointer to the interface does not compile with an error `item.get_name undefined (type *I is pointer to interface, not interface)`.
Changing from `*I` to `I` solves the error.

What I'd like to know is WHY the difference? The first function is very common as it allows a single function to be used with various structs as long as they implement the `I` interface.

Also, how come that the function compiles when it is defined to accept `I` but it actually receives a *pointer* (`&Foo{}`)? Should the function expect something like `Foo{}` (i.e. NOT a pointer)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44372954/2664120 maybe this answer helps you?

Comment: There’s no reason to use a pointer to an interface. Just remove them all and there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix to this is to make the `print_item1` just accept an `I` rather than an pointer to `I`.

```
func print_item1(item I)
```

The reason for this is that `*Foo` satisfies the `I` interface but remember that `*Foo` is not an `*I`.

I would highly suggest reading [Russ Cox's explanation of the implementation of interfaces](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces)

Comment: The reason behind why is right, I would not really suggest accepting `I` without knowing the context tho.