# Can't assign a struct pointer to a interface pointer

Tags: go, struct, interface, polymorphism

The struct `Dog` implemetments all the methods of interface `Animal`, why does `*Dos` can't be assigned to `*Animal` ?

```
type Animal interface {
    run()
}

type Dog struct {
    name string
}

func (d *Dog) run() {
    fmt.Println( d.name , " is running")
}

func main(){
    var d *Dog
    var a *Animal

    d = new(Dog)
    d.run()
    a = d   //errors here
}
```

Go informs the following errros:

```
Cannot use 'd' (type *Dog) as type *Animal in assignment
```

Answer (score 4):

A variable with an interface type is already a pointer; you don't need to declare it as a pointer to an interface. Just do `var a Animal` and it will work.

Comment: You can use a pointer to an interface variable to change the value of the variable from another scope. If you have `func f(a Animal)` then you can use `a` in the function to invoke `Animal` methods, but if you change the value of `a` itself, that change is only visible within `f`. If you instead write `func f(a *Animal)` then `a` is now a pointer to some interface variable defined elsewhere, and you can change that variable by setting `*a`.

Answer (score 1):

You must remove pointer from interface.

```go
//Animal interface
type Animal interface {
    run()
}

//Dog struct
type Dog struct {
    name string
}

func (d *Dog) run() {
    fmt.Println(d.name, "is running")
}

func main() {
    var d *Dog
    var a Animal

    d = new(Dog)
    d.name = "Putty"
    d.run()
    a = d //errors here
    a.run()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`Dog` is a type, so `*Dog` is.

`Dog` DOES NOT implement the interface `Animal`, but `*Dog` does.

So `var a Animal = new(Dog)` is ok.

Comment: If I use `Dog` to implement `Animal`, `var a *Animal=new(Dog) ` fails too!  Why? @HolaYang

Comment: That's another problem, a pointer to interface is almost never useful in golang.w

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370277/type-is-pointer-to-interface-not-interface-confusion) for more information.