# How to get pointer to interface in GO

Tags: pointers, go, casting, temporary

I would like to get rid of the variable temp in the following code:

```
type myinterface interface {
    f1()
}

type a struct {
    val int
}

type b struct {
    mi *myinterface
}

func (a) f1() {

}

    func demo() {

        a1 := a{3}
        var temp myinterface = a1
        b1 := b{&temp}
        fmt.Println(b1)
```

But if I try to write

```
b1 := b{&myinterface(a1)}
```

I get the message

> cannot take the address of myinterface(a1) ( undefined )

what is the correct way to do this?

**Update:**

I did not a pointer to an interface, since an interface can hold a struct or a pointer to a struct, as also detailed in this question:

["<type> is pointer to interface, not interface" confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370277/type-is-pointer-to-interface-not-interface-confusion)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me know if this is what you are looking for:
https://play.golang.org/p/ZGRyIqN7bPR

Full code:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

type myinterface interface {
  f1()
}

type a struct {
  val int
}

type b struct {
  mi myinterface
}

func (a) f1() {}


func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

  a1 := &a{3}
  b1 := b{a1}
  fmt.Println(b1)
}
```

You almost never need a pointer to an interface, since interfaces are just pointers themselves.
So just change the struct b to:

```
 type b struct {
   mi myinterface
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's almost exactly what I needed. I just changed it to a1 := a{3}
        b1 := b{&a1}. I think you should put the source in the answer rather than provide a link. Then I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 6):

`myinterface(a1)` is a type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions), it converts `a1` to type `myinteface`.

Type conversion expressions are not addressable, so you cannot take the address of it. What is addressable is listed explicitly in the [Spec: Address operators:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators)

> The operand must be *addressable*, that is, either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation; or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array indexing operation of an addressable array. As an exception to the addressability requirement, `x` [in the expression of `&x`] may also be a (possibly parenthesized) [composite literal](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

This related answer lists several options how to obtain the address of such expressions: [How do I do a literal *int64 in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716354/how-do-i-do-a-literal-int64-in-go/30716481#30716481)

For example if you use a composite literal to create a slice of type `[]myinterface` and put `a1` in it, you can take the address of its first element (which will be of type `*myinterface`):

```
b1 := b{&[]myinterface{a1}[0]}
```

And it will work (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ExWeqrXKikU)):

```
a1 := a{3}
b1 := b{&[]myinterface{a1}[0]}
fmt.Println(b1)
```

**But know that using pointers to interfaces is very rarely needed, so is a field of type `*myinterface` really what you want in the first place?**

Interface values can be `nil`, and also `nil` values (e.g. `nil` pointers) can also be wrapped in interfaces, so most likely you don't need a pointer to interface. We would have to know your "wider" goal to tell if this is what you really need.

Comment: You are correct, I did not need a pointer to an interface. I wanted to hold data through an interface, but also have it point to the original data, not create a copy.  What I didn't realize is that the address of the data is also assignable to the interface.