# [Golang]confused at Nil pointer interface and nil interface

Tags: go

Recently, I am reading "The Go Progrmming Language"  Book. In the chapter 7.5, I am confused about below code. Why f(buf) will panic but f(w)?

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var w io.Writer
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", w)

    f(w)

    w = os.Stdout
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", w)

    w = new(bytes.Buffer)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", w)

    var buf *bytes.Buffer
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", buf)
    f(buf)
}

func f(out io.Writer)  {

    fmt.Printf("%T\n", out)
    if out != nil {
        out.Write([]byte("done!\n"))
    }
}
```

Comment: `buf` pass as a pointer `*bytes.Buffer` to `f()`. **Pointers** are special types that contain the memory address of the underlying value. An **interface** at runtime holds an object that implements its interface. You can also check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44372954/2536252

Comment: See [Why is my nil error value not equal to nil?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error) for an explanation.

Comment: I think all of you answer haven't hit the point.  How can you expect a golang newbie know the internal implementation of Go?

Answer (score 2):

An interface type, in Go, is a pair containing the underlying type and the value. When you create an interface variable:

```
var w io.Writer
```

it is initialized to its zero value, which, for interfaces, is `nil`. When you pass this to a function that expects an `io.Writer`, it is passed as `nil`.

The initialization is similar for a non-interface pointer variable:

```
var buf *bytes.Buffer
```

Here, `buf` is `nil`. However, when you pass `buf` to a function that takes `io.Writer`, it has to be passed in as an interface. Go converts the `buf` value to an interface where the type is `*bytes.Buffer` and underlying value is `nil`. However, this interface itself is not `nil`.

Comment: Maybe you can paste the Type struct and give out how a variable in go represented in inner go implementation. That will be much clear.