# *boolean isn't compatible with *interface{}

Tags: go, pointers, inheritance

I have a type like this

```golang
type Transformer func(raw string) (*interface{}, error)
```

I need a function for boolean

```golang
var TransformBoolean Transformer = func(raw string) (*interface{}, error) {
     var value bool
     if raw == "true" {
          value = true
     } else if raw == "false" {
          value = false
     } else {
          return nil, Error{"Invalid"}
     }
     return &value, nil // <-- Here's the error
}
```

The function return type is interface{} because it can return ints, booleans, floats, etc.
But, the compiler doesn't let me return a *boolean as a *interface{}

Comment: Never use a pointer to an interface. It practically never makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

`value` is a boolean so `&value` is a pointer to an boolean (not a pointer to an `interface{}`). If you want to return a pointer to an interface then you could use:

```
x := interface{}(value)
return &x, nil
```

See [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lyfsthIEseq).

However there are not many situations where taking the address of an interface is useful (see the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370277/type-is-pointer-to-interface-not-interface-confusion)) so it may be worth considering whether this is necessary.