# Changing pointer type and value under interface with reflection

Tags: pointers, go, reflection, interface

Is it possible to change pointer type and value of variable defined by interface?

I can change pointer value with reflection: `v.Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(&Greeter{"Jack"}).Elem())` which is equivalent to `a = &Greeter{"Jack"}`.

But how can I make a reflection equivalent for `a = &Greeter2{"Jack"}`?

UPDATE: Unfortunately in real problem that I'm trying to solve I can not address original variable (`panic: reflect: reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value`), that's why I'm trying to workaround at pointer level.

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/CBKuyQFCiH) is full example code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Greeter struct {
    Name string
}

func (g *Greeter) String() string {
    return "Hello, My name is " + g.Name
}

type Greeter2 struct {
    Name string
}

func (g *Greeter2) String() string {
    return "Hello, My name is " + g.Name
}

func main() {
    var a fmt.Stringer
    a = &Greeter{"John"}

    v := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    v.Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(&Greeter{"Jack"}).Elem())
    //v.Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(&Greeter2{"Jack"}).Elem()) // panic: reflect.Set: value of type main.Greeter2 is not assignable to type main.Greeter
    fmt.Println(a.String()) // Hello, My name is Jack

    a = &Greeter2{"Ron"}
    fmt.Println(a.String()) // Hello, My name is Ron
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything in Go is passed by value. Interfaces too. When you pass a value of interface type, a copy of the interface value will be made (along with the `(value;type)` inside it), and you will only be able to modify the copy which will not affect the original.

You have a variable `a` of interface type. If you want to modify the value stored in this variable, you have to pass / use the address of this variable.

First let's modify the `Greeter2.String()` method to know which one gets called:

```
func (g *Greeter2) String() string {
    return "Hello2, My name is " + g.Name
}
```

And also call `a.String()` after first init to see that it originally does contain a `*Greeter` value as we'll soon change it.

```
var a fmt.Stringer
a = &Greeter{"John"}
fmt.Println(a.String()) // Hello, My name is John

v := reflect.ValueOf(&a).Elem()
v.Set(reflect.ValueOf(&Greeter2{"Jack"}))
fmt.Println(a.String()) // Hello2, My name is Jack

a = &Greeter2{"Ron"}
fmt.Println(a.String()) // Hello2, My name is Ron
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oZqXeWlrKK)):

```
Hello, My name is John
Hello2, My name is Jack
Hello2, My name is Ron
```

So essentially there is no such thing as changing the value and type of an interface *value*, only changing the data in a variable (that has a memory address) that may be of interface type.

So the key things were:

1. Start from an address: `reflect.ValueOf(&a)`
2. And you have to set a pointer value into it as only `*Greeter2` implements `fmt.String`, but not `Greeter`. See [Go, X does not implement Y (... method has a pointer receiver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823315/go-x-does-not-implement-y-method-has-a-pointer-receiver/40824044#40824044) for details.

For more details and in-depth introducation, read: [The Go Blog: The Laws of Reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)

**Edit: about modifying a copy**

First section of my answer: Whenever you pass something a copy is made. This also includes passing an interface value to `reflect.ValueOf()`: that will also receive a copy, so you can't avoid this. Only way to make this work is to pass a *pointer*; because the pointer will also be copied, but we're modifying the *pointed* value (not the pointer) which is the same.

Comment: Unfortunately I missed essential thing in my question, I need reflection trick to affect copies of `a`. 

I'm trying to fix https://github.com/boolean64/inject/blob/master/inject_test.go#L227 to work with `Greeter2`. In that case original variable is not settable `panic: reflect: reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value`.

Comment: @vearutop Not possible as calling `reflect.ValueOf()` already makes a (another) copy, so at most you could only modify the copy of copy. See edited answer.