# Implement interface with pointer

Tags: go

Look at this code. Everything works fine:

```
type moninterface2 interface {
    methode_commune(a,b int) int
}

type classe1 struct {
    a, b int
}

type classe2 struct {
    c, d int
}

func (r classe1) methode_commune(a,b int) int {
    return a+b
}

func (r classe2) methode_commune(a,b int) int {
    return a*b
}

func fonctiontest(param moninterface2) {
    ret := param.methode_commune(2,3)
    fmt.Println(ret)
}
```

But if I declare `methode_commune` like this:

```
func (r *classe1) methode_commune(a,b int) int 
func (r *classe2) methode_commune(a,b int) int
```

Go does not consider `classe1` and `classe2` implements `moninterface2` and the code does not compile. I do not understand why.

Comment: What is the compilation error you receive? It probably tells you why.

Comment: It does compile for me. Can you give more detail? https://play.golang.org/p/hUCFWu5tl1

Comment: Make sure to pass a pointer instead of just a value. E.g. `fonctiontest(&classe1{})` is ok, `fonctiontest(classe1{})` is **not** ok.

Comment: Check out this question: [Go, X does not implement Y (… method has a pointer receiver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823315/go-x-does-not-implement-y-method-has-a-pointer-receiver/40824044#40824044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Go does not consider `classe1` and `classe2` implements `moninterface2` and
>   the code does not compile. I do not understand why.

Because after you change the working code to this:

```
func (r *classe1) methode_commune(a,b int) int 
func (r *classe2) methode_commune(a,b int) int
```

the two types, `classe1` and `classe2`, do not implement the interface anymore, instead the two types `*classe1` and `*classe2` implement the `moninterface2` interface.

`T` and `*T` are not one and the same type.

Therefore to make the code compile you'll have to pass a **pointer to** `classe1` or `classe2` whereever the `moninterface2` interface is expected. E.g. `fonctiontest(&classe1{})`.