# Cannot use implementation of interface as argument to func that wants interface

Tags: go, reflection, interface

I'm getting the following error:

```
./main.go:31: cannot use telegramService (type messaging.TelegramService) as type mypackage.MessagingService in argument to mypackage.RegisterMessagingService:
    messaging.TelegramService does not implement mypackage.MessagingService (wrong type for HandleIncomingMessage method)
        have HandleIncomingMessage(telegram.Message) error
        want HandleIncomingMessage(mypackage.IncomingMessage) error
```

I have an interface that describes a messaging service like Telegram or WhatsApp, and an interface that describes an incoming message from one of those services:

```
// IncomingMessage is a message that comes in on a messaging service
type IncomingMessage interface {
    Send() error
}

// MessagingService is a service on which messages can be send (like Telegram or FB Messenger)
type MessagingService interface {
    Start()
    HandleIncomingMessage(IncomingMessage) error
    GetHTTPHandler() http.HandlerFunc
    GetCommands() []MessagingCommand
}
```

The first implementation of `MessagingService` is for Telegram. The issue is the `HandleIncomingMessage` function, which currently doesn't really do anything and just looks like this:

```
// HandleIncomingMessage will take an incoming message and repond to it
func (s TelegramService) HandleIncomingMessage(msg *telegram.Message) error {

    return nil
}
```

The issue is that this function accepts a `telegram.Message`, which the compiler says doesn't comply with the interface. The thing is, that `telegram.Message` is an *implementation* of `IncomingMessage`:

```
// Message is a Telegram message
type Message struct {
    // Added the line below at some point, but it didn't work without it either
    mypackage.IncomingMessage
    MessageID uint64 `json:"message_id"`
    FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
    Username  string `json:"username"`
    Date      uint64 `json:"date"`
    Text      string `json:"text"`
    Chat      Chat   `json:"chat"`
    From      User   `json:"from"`
}

// Send will take m and send it
func (m Message) Send() error {
    // Do stuff

    return nil
}
```

Initially `IncomingMessage` was an empty interface, which is where I first noticed the issue. I tried adding the function `Send()` which I was going to add anyway, as I thought maybe just giving it any struct wouldnt't work. However, I'm still getting this error.

I don't see any reason why `telegram.Message` doesn't implement the interface, it's pretty straight forward.

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

PS: My package isn't actually called `mypackage`, changed for clarity

Comment: The method signature is `HandleIncomingMessage(IncomingMessage) error`. You can't use a different signature, but why do you need to at all?

Comment: The compiler's complaint is valid. TelegramService is not able to handle *any* IncomingMessage, only some and thus does not satisfy the MessagingService interface.

Comment: @JimB Thanks sir. If I use IncomingMessage, can I just use it as if it were a telegram.Message?

Comment: @RoemerBakker: I don't understand. If you want it to be an interface, then you use it through its interface methods. You can always assert it to a concrete type, but then why have the interface in the first place?

Comment: @JimB This function is specific to Telegram. However, I'll be implementing other messaging services along side logic to store incoming message in a database. In this case I want the IncomingMessage to be an interface so that I can write general stuff for the db storage. Though again, those incoming messages will have specific functionality as well

Comment: Does it help if you make your methods have a pointer receiver? `func (s *TelegramService) Han..` and `func (m *Message) Send()`.

Comment: What does actual error say? Could be related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823315/go-x-does-not-implement-y-method-has-a-pointer-receiver?noredirect=1&lq=1. As Graham mentions you might need to change just this `func (m *Message) Send() error {`

Answer (score 0):

`HandleIncomingMessage` must take an `IncomingMessage` argument since that's the way the interface is defined. You can't define an implementation of `HandleIncomingMessage` that takes some other type as the argument, even if that type implements `IncomingMessage`. You can define your function to take `IncomingMessage` and convert that to `*telegram.Message` using a type assertion:

```
func (s TelegramService) HandleIncomingMessage(im IncomingMessage) error {
    msg := im.(*telegram.Message)
    return nil
}
```

I'm assuming you actually want to be using a pointer to `telegram.Message`. If so, you need to change the definition of the `Send`  method to take a pointer receiver.