# About method implementation for an interface

Tags: go

Can anyone explain why the calling of a.Abs() works?
In my opinion, 'a' is a variable of type *Vertex, but the type *Vertex doesn't implement the method Abs.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Abser interface {
    Abs() float64
}

func main() {
    var a Abser

    v := Vertex{3, 4}
    a = &v // a *Vertex implements Abser
    // In the following line, v is a *Vertex (not Vertex)
    // and does NOT implement Abser, but why does this calling work?
    fmt.Println(a.Abs())

}

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From the [fine specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets):

> **Method sets**
>   [...] The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods declared with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method set of T). [...]

Your `Abs` function is in the method sets of both `Vertex` and `*Vertex` so `*Vertex` is an `Abser` just like `Vertex` is.

Other related sections:

- [**Method values**](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values)
- [**Selectors**](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)

In general, pointers are automatically dereferenced when possible so you can say `x.M()` and `x.V` without worrying about whether or not `x` is a pointer and there is no need for C's `->` or manual dereferencing (i.e. `(*x).M()` or `(*x).V`).

Comment: Yes, I know the compiler would automatically dereference a pointer when calling a method that accepts a value receiver. But, what I'm talking about is the interface. See this [tutorial example]( https://tour.golang.org/methods/9)

Comment: I'm just trying to say that the automatic dereferencing is more general than just during method calls and property accesses, it also applies to the type's method set.

Comment: If *Vertex implements Abser just like Vertex, why the [tutorial example](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9) emphasizes that v (of type Vertex) does NOT implement Abser.

Comment: Look carefully at the tour example. It has `func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64` whereas you have `func (v Vertex) Abs() float64`. There is automatic dereferencing but it doesn't go the other way.

Comment: see this [example](https://tour.golang.org/methods/7).Abs has a value receiver (Vertex), and using a variable of type *Vertex to call abs is fine.

Comment: And that's exactly what you're doing in your question and that's what the specification says. What am I missing?

Comment: In the [example](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9), if assigning 'v' of type Vertex to the interface 'a' is illegal, why assigning v of type Vertex* in my question is legal since Vertex* doesn't implement the interface.

Comment: The tour example defines an `Abs` method specifically on `*Vertex`, your question defines it on `Vertex`. Dereferencing is (more or less) automatic, addressing is not. If a method is defined on `T` then it is automatically defined on `*T`; if a method is defined on `*T` then it is not automatically defined on `T`.

Comment: " if a method is defined on *T then it is not automatically defined on T." 
I doubt if it's true. Please see the [example](https://tour.golang.org/methods/6). 
 "while methods with pointer receivers take either a value or a pointer as the receiver when they are called:"

Does it mean if a method is defined on *T, then it is automatically defined on T?

Comment: Thanks for discussing with me. I found a thread relating to my question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823315/go-x-does-not-implement-y-method-has-a-pointer-receiver