# Why does this Type Assertion on a direct implemented interface fail?

Tags: go, methods, interface, composition, type-assertion

I am struggling with Go's Type Assertion mechanism. In the below example the Type Assertion for `Qux.(Bar)` fails.

Why does a direct implementation of `DoBar()` at `Qux` not fullfill the `Bar` interface?

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

type Nameable interface {
    Name() string
}

type Foo interface {
    Nameable
    DoFoo() string
}

type Bar interface {
    Nameable
    DoBar() string
}

type bar struct {
    name string
}

func (b bar) Name() string {
    return b.name
}

// Qux embeds bar and is expected to fullfill Nameable interface
type Qux struct {
    bar
}

func (q *Qux) DoBar() string {
    return "DoBar"
}

func Check(subject Nameable) {
    if N, ok := subject.(Nameable); ok {
        fmt.Printf("%s has Nameable\n", N.Name())
    } 

    if F, ok := subject.(Foo); ok {
        fmt.Printf("%s has Foo: %s\n", F.Name(), F.DoFoo())
    }

    if B, ok := subject.(Bar); ok {
        fmt.Printf("%s has Bar: %s\n", B.Name(), B.DoBar())
    }
}

func main() {
    Check(bar{name: "bar"})
    Check(Qux{bar: bar{name: "Qux"}})
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/PPkUMUu58JW

Output:

```
bar has Nameable
Qux has Nameable
```

Comment: Only *CUx has a DoBar. Stop trying to simulate inheritance by embedding. Embedding is just syntactical sugar. Write out the Embeddings and you'll see.

Comment: @Volker But `Qux` fails at the Type Assertion `subject.(Bar)` although it implements `DoBar()` itself?!

Comment: No it does not have a DoBar method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Qux.DoBar()` has pointer receiver, so only `*Qux` implements `Bar` but not `Qux`. The type `Qux` and the pointer type to it `*Qux` are different types with different [method sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets).

Using a value of type `*Qux` does implement `Bar`:

```
Check(&Qux{bar: bar{name: "*Qux"}})
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SPBg4Gz3gSG)):

```
*Qux has Nameable
*Qux has Bar: DoBar
```

Also if you change the receiver of `Qux.DoBar()` to be non-pointer:

```
func (q Qux) DoBar() string {
    return "DoBar"
}
```

Then both `Qux` and `*Qux` will implement `Bar`:

```
Check(bar{name: "bar"})
Check(Qux{bar: bar{name: "Qux"}})
Check(&Qux{bar: bar{name: "*Qux"}})
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qanZTG2KIV4)):

```
bar has Nameable
Qux has Nameable
Qux has Bar: DoBar
*Qux has Nameable
*Qux has Bar: DoBar
```

See related question: [X does not implement Y (... method has a pointer receiver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823315/x-does-not-implement-y-method-has-a-pointer-receiver/40824044#40824044)

Comment: Thank you, @icza.