# Unexpected behavior in Go structs

Tags: go, embedding

I faced a strange behavior in Go structs. I might be misunderstanding something but when I created like so:

```
type ITest interface {
    Foo() string
    Bar(string)
}

type Base struct {
    value string
}

func (b Base) Foo () string {
    return b.value
}

func (b *Base) Bar (val string) {
    b.value = val
}
// Not implementing ITest
type Sub struct {
    Base
}
// Now it works
type Sub struct {
    *Base
}
```

Then `Sub` is not implementing `ITest`. But if I change `Sub` to embed pointer of `Base` it starts to implement `ITest`. I know it somehow related to caller in methods but come on. So the question is: Is that me Going wrong or Go have problems with embedding logic?

Comment: See [X does not implement Y (… method has a pointer receiver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823315/x-does-not-implement-y-method-has-a-pointer-receiver/40824044#40824044) (2nd part of the answer: Structs and embedding). Also: [Why does this Type Assertion on a direct implemented interface fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52739991/why-does-this-type-assertion-on-a-direct-implemented-interface-fail)

Comment: You ca use both the implementations of Sub but you need to use a pointer in the first case. For example  https://play.golang.org/p/1zPXfsJacBt

Answer (score 1):

`*Base` has a method `Bar`, but `Base` does not; so `Base` does not implement `ITest`. Thus, embedding a `*Base` allows `Sub` to implement the interface.

Your use of the names `Base` and `Sub` also implies you may be conflating composition and inheritance, which you should be very careful with in Go. *There is no inheritance in Go*. There are no base classes, no subclasses, no class hierarchy, no inheritance. The *only* form of polymorphism in go is interfaces.