# Setting a value via an interface in go

Tags: pointers, go, methods, interface

In the following example, I'd like to call the `setvalue()` of the `b` object via an interface procedure.

I'd like to use an interface because I need  to insert different kinds of objects in a list, possibly very big, each obeying a common interface.

However the compiler complains with the following error :

> ./tests.go:27:6: cannot use newbox(3) (type box) as type container in assignment:
>       box does not implement container (setValue method has pointer receiver)

Probably I have to define the interface differently, but how?

I know I could transform the setvalue procedure in a function, returning the updated box, but since the object can be very large, and he procedure will be called several times, i'd like to pass the object via a pointer.

Really isn't there a way to define an interface method that receive the calling structure via a pointer?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type container interface {
  setValue (val int)
}

//--------------------------------------
// box is a kind of container

type box struct {
      value int
}

func newbox (x int) box {
    return box {x}
}

func (cnt *box) setValue(val int) {
    (*cnt).value = val
}


// -----------------------------------------------

func main() {
    var b container = newbox(3)  // HERE IS THE ERROR
    fmt.Printf("%v\n",b)
    b.setValue(5)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n",b)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [X does not implement Y (... method has a pointer receiver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823315/x-does-not-implement-y-method-has-a-pointer-receiver)

Comment: tl;dr: change `newbox()` to return a pointer: `func newbox (x int) *box { return &box{x} }` (but see that link for a more complete explanation).

Comment: well, this is depressing...
so I can't have an interface specifying both "value" procedures (getters) than "pointer procedures" (setters) ?

Comment: @MaurizioFerreira  The [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) for a pointer type includes the methods for value receivers (`box` in the question) and pointer receivers (`*box` in the question).

Comment: Ok, so changing the function newBox to returning a pointer solves the problem.
I'm able to define setters and getters procedure.
Thanks to all.