# How to assert on error types in Go tests?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a error type like below defined

```
type RetryableError struct {
    msg string
}

func (a *RetryableError) Error() string {
    return a.msg
}
```

In a unit test, what is the Go way of asserting if the error returned is of `RetryableError` type?

Comment: This, along with many other Go basics, is covered in the Tour of Go: https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use type assertion:

```
err := someFunc()
if retryable, ok := err.(*RetryableError); ok {
   // use retryable
}
```

Your `RetryableError` is not an error, but `*RetryableError` is. To correct:

```
func (a RetryableError) Error() string {
    return a.msg
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QZN2tgGW8RC). The error has a wonderful description on [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823315/x-does-not-implement-y-method-has-a-pointer-receiver), but I still haven't found the right way to typecheck for errors.

Comment: Yes it does. Your `Retryable` is not an error, but `*Retryable` is: https://play.golang.org/p/qwpPFSB0R_b

Comment: @BurakSerdar Maybe you could edit your answer accordingly to avoid confusion?

Comment: IMO, tests are supposed to be deterministic and any condition in tests are to be avoided since they increase cyclomatic complexity. If such conditions are really needed, they themselves should be tested. `assert`/`require` are prefered, though.

Answer (score 5):

[`assert.IsType`](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert#Assertions.IsType)

Snippet from https://medium.com/@sebdah/go-best-practices-testing-3448165a0e18:

```
func TestDivision(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct{
        x      float64
        y      float64
        result float64
        err    error
    }{
        { x: 1.0, y: 2.0, result: 0.5, err: nil },
        { x: -1.0, y: 2.0, result: -0.5, err: nil},
        { x: 1.0, y: 0.0, result: 0.0, err: ErrZeroDivision},
    }
    for _, test := range tests {
        result, err := divide(test.x, test.y)
        assert.IsType(t, test.err, err)
        assert.Equal(t, test.result, result)
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you install [testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify) for those `assert`s