# Generic interface types with pointer recievers

Tags: go, generics

I am trying to unify some logic in my backend app to map between models (db specific types) and the dto types (core logic types) in my system using Generics and am running into this interesting situation.

I have an interface for a `Model` that backs a type `T` and has methods to convert to/from this type as defined below along with 2 generic functions that convert lists between the two for any `Model` implementation

```golang
// data/models/model.go

package models

type Model[T any] interface {
    ToType() *T
    FromType(*T)
}

// FromTypeSlice converts a slice of T to a slice of Model[T]
func FromTypeSlice[Type any, ModelType Model[Type]](t *[]Type) []ModelType {
    modelSlice := make([]ModelType, len(*t))
    for i, typeObject := range *t {
        modelSlice[i].FromType(&typeObject)
    }
    return modelSlice
}

// ToTypeSlice converts a slice of Model[T] to a slice of T
func ToTypeSlice[Type any, ModelType Model[Type]](types *[]ModelType) *[]Type {
    typeSlice := make([]Type, len(*types))
    for i, model := range *types {
        typeSlice[i] = *model.ToType()
    }
    return &typeSlice
}
```

Below I have some test cases to validate the behavior of the interface and the two functions. However it does not compile due to the error

```
sampleModel does not satisfy Model[sampleType] (method FromType has pointer receiver)
```

If I remove the pointer from ToType/FromType it compiles, however since the value is not a pointer any updates made to it do not carry over and the test fails. Specifically the `FromType` method.

What is the reason for this constraint?

```
// data/models/model_test.go

package models

import "testing"

type sampleModel struct {
    ID int
}

type sampleType struct {
    ID int
}

func (model *sampleModel) ToType() *sampleType {
    return &sampleType{
        ID: model.ID,
    }
}

func (model *sampleModel) FromType(t *sampleType) {
    model.ID = t.ID
}

func TestFromTypeSlice(t *testing.T) {
    slice := []sampleType{{ID: 1}, {ID: 2}, {ID: 3}}
    modelSlice := FromTypeSlice[sampleType, sampleModel](&slice)

    if len(modelSlice) != len(slice) {
        t.Errorf("Expected length of modelSlice to be %d, got %d", len(slice), len(modelSlice))
    }

    for i, model := range modelSlice {
        if model.ID != slice[i].ID {
            t.Errorf("Expected modelSlice[%d].ID to be %d, got %d", i, slice[i].ID, model.ID)
        }
    }
}

func TestToTypeSlice(t *testing.T) {
    slice := []sampleModel{{ID: 1}, {ID: 2}, {ID: 3}}
    typeSlice := ToTypeSlice[sampleType, sampleModel](&slice)

    if len(*typeSlice) != len(slice) {
        t.Errorf("Expected length of modelSlice to be %d, got %d", len(slice), len(*typeSlice))
    }

    for i, ty := range *typeSlice {
        if ty.ID != slice[i].ID {
            t.Errorf("Expected modelSlice[%d].ID to be %d, got %d", i, slice[i].ID, ty.ID)
        }
    }
}
```

Outside of generics it works fine as demonstrated by this test below:

```golang
func TestFromType(t *testing.T) {
    var model Model[sampleType] = &sampleModel{}
    model.FromType(&sampleType{ID: 1})

    if model.ToType().ID != 1 {
        t.Errorf("Expected model.ToType().ID to be 1, got %d", model.ToType().ID)
    }
}
```

If you wish to play with it here is a go playground link: https://play.golang.com/p/_FqTR5DMvju

Comment: The type doesn't implement the interface, only a pointer to the type implements the interface.

Comment: Basically, `ToType` and `FromType` are in the method set of `*sampleModel` but not `sampleModel`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40824044/8468264

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand it now. Coming from C# where generics work very differently how go interacts with pointers and Generics seems weird to me.