# Go method call shorthand spec applicability

Tags: go, methods, specifications

From the *Calls* section of Go spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls

> A method call `x.m()` is valid if the method set of (the type of) `x` contains `m` and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list of `m`. If `x` is addressable and `&x`'s method set contains `m`, `x.m()` is shorthand for `(&x).m()`

My program.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    p := Point{2, 3}

    p.FakeScale(10)
    fmt.Println(p)

    p.RealScale(10)
    fmt.Println(p)
}

type Point struct {
    x int
    y int
}

func (p Point) FakeScale(s int) {
    p.x *= s
    p.y *= s
}

func (p *Point) RealScale(s int) {
    p.x *= s
    p.y *= s
}
```

Here is the output.

```
{2, 3}
{20, 30}
```

My question is specifically about this part of the spec.

> If `x` is addressable and `&x`'s method set contains `m`, `x.m()` is shorthand for `(&x).m()`

My questions.

1. Is the quoted part applicable to `p.FakeScale(10)`? My guess is "No" because although `p` is addressable, `&p`'s method set does not contain `FakeScale`. `p`'s method set contains `FakeScale` because it uses value receiver, but `p`'s method set does not contain `FakeScale`, therefore this part of the spec is not applicable to `p.FakeScale(10)`. Am I correct?
2. Is the quoted part applicable to `p.RealScale(10)`? My guess is "Yes" because `p` is addressable and `&p`'s method set contains `RealScale` by virtue of it using a pointer receiver. Therefore, this part of the spec is applicable to `p.RealScale(10)`. Am I correct?
3. Can you provide an example code where `x.m()` is valid but `x` is not addressable, and thus this part of the spec is not applicable?

Comment: What exactly does `addressable` mean? Does it simply mean that the value is NOT `nil`?