# Nested struct is not updated

Tags: go

I have a nested struct. I want to update it inside a method.
For some reason, the update doesn't take place.

```
    package main

    import "fmt"

    type B struct {
        c int
    }

    type A struct {
        b B
    }

    func (a A) updateB(n int) {
        a.b.c = n
    }

    func main() {
        a := A{b: B{c: 5}}

        fmt.Println(a)
        a.updateB(42)
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
```

The output I get is

```
{{5}}
{{5}}
```

In most languages, I'd expect it to be updated. Is this some special Go behavior? How does one go about updating nested structs in Go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you are using a value receiver so the updateB method receives a copy of the value of `A` rather than a pointer to the memory that contains the `a` variable.  Using a pointer receiver fixes the problem:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type B struct {
    c int
}

type A struct {
    b B
}

func (a *A) updateB(n int) {
    a.b.c = n
}

func main() {
    a := A{b: B{c: 5}}

    fmt.Println(a)
    a.updateB(42)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/XBrxd246qT3

See also:

[Value receiver vs. Pointer receiver in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775376/value-receiver-vs-pointer-receiver-in-golang)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your update function. You are supposed to add it to the pointer to A.

```
func (a *A) updateB(n int) {
    a.b.c = n
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not because the struct is nested, rather it's because you need a pointer receiver to modify the value to which the receiver points, in this case your `a` variable.

Without the pointer your `UpdateB` method would only be updating a copy of the original A struct value.

See the following:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type B struct {
    c int
}

type A struct {
    b B
}

func (a *A) UpdateB(n int) {
    a.b.c = n
}

func main() {
    a := A{b: B{c: 5}}

    fmt.Println(a)
    a.UpdateB(50)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For any interface for its objects to be updated by a function you need to pass the object by reference.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type B struct {
    c int
}

type A struct {
    b B
}

func (a *A) updateB(n int) {
    a.b.c = n
}

func main() {
    a := A{b: B{c: 5}}

    fmt.Println(a)
    a.updateB(42)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/_o5sRApo6WP