# structs implementing interface methods either as pointer receiver or value receiver

Tags: go, methods, interface

I have few methods in my interface. I have struct that implements those methods. I noticed that it is not possible to implements set of methods as a pointer receiver and few as value receiver.

below is an interface

```
type ContractCRUD interface {
    addContract() bool
    deleteContract() bool
    updateContract() bool
    addAPI(apipath string) bool
    getContractByNameAndGroup(user string, group APIGroup) error
    getObject() Contract
}
```

struct that will implement the ContractCRUD Interface

```
type Contract struct {
    id             int64
    User           string
    Group          APIGroup
    AllowedRequest int64
    Window         int16
}
```

just listing out the functions definition..

```
func (c Contract) getObject() Contract {...}
func (c Contract) addContract() bool {...}
.
.
.
func (c *Contract) getContractByNameAndGroup(user string, group APIGroup) error {..}
```

with such an implementation, even the getObject and addContact, expect the pointer receiver.

```
func RegisterAPI(c ContractCRUD) bool {
    contract := c.getObject()
    fmt.Printf("Register the user %s under the group %s with the limit %d per %d minute(s)\n", contract.User, contract.Group, contract.AllowedRequest, contract.Window)
    return c.addContract()
}
```

somewhere in main

```
...
registration.RegisterAPI(*c)
```

i get the following error

```
cannot use *c (type registration.Contract) as type registration.ContractCRUD in argument to registration.RegisterAPI:
    registration.Contract does not implement registration.ContractCRUD (registration.getContractByNameAndGroup method has pointer receiver)
```

So I understand I cannot have the mix of the implementation, but I don't seem to understand why. I am  fairly new to Go. I apologies if this is something very obvious. I tried reading around, but I only found everyone talking about the when to use pointer and value implementation.

Comment: You can actually mix them, but it's generally good practice not to.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27775558/13860

Comment: From: https://tour.golang.org/methods/8  "In general, all methods on a given type should have either value or pointer receivers, but not a mixture of both. (We'll see why over the next few pages.)"

Comment: The [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) value type does not include the pointer receiver methods.  The method set for the pointer type does include the value receiver methods.  Register the pointer: `registration.RegisterAPI(c)`

Answer (score 1):

You can mix value and pointer receivers in the methods for a type, and the types will be converted if you call a method with a value receiver on a pointer object or if you call a method with a pointer receiver on a non-pointer object (assuming it's addressable). However, if you need a certain type to implement an interface, that type must have all of the methods of the interface defined. In your example, you can have the type `Contract` implement the interface if all the methods are defined with value receivers, or you can have the type `*Contract` implement the interface if all the methods are defined with pointer receivers. The important point here is that `Contract` and `*Contract` are distinct types, so whichever type you want to implement the interface has to have all of the interface methods defined on it.