# A confusion about interface assignments

Tags: go

I am very confused about the following Go code. Who can tell me why

1. `worker=u` and `work=&u` are valid?
2. `worker=p` is valid?
3. `worker=&p` is invalid?
4. What is difference between User and People?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Worker interface {
    Work()
}

type User struct {
    name string
}

func (u User) Work() {

}

type People struct {
    name string
}

func (p *People) Work() {

}

func main() {
    var worker Worker

    u := User{name:"xxx"}
    worker = u  // valid
    worker = &u  // valid

    p := People{name:"xxx"}
    worker = p  // invalid
    worker = &p  // valid

}
```

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets and https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors point 3.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27775376/13860

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `worker=u` and `work=&u` are valid because `User` implement all methods of `Worker` in this case only `Work` method with values for receivers. Value methods can be invoked on both value and pointer.
2. `worker=p` is invalid as `People` implements `Work` method with with pointer for receivers. So if you assign any value of `People` to `Worker` pointer then if will not `Work` method. That's why it is invalid.
3. `worker=&p` is valid as `People` implements `Work` method.
4. User and People are two different struct that implement same interface `Worker`. This ensures that both have a method named `Work` but the implementation may be different.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Worker interface {
    Work()
}

type User struct {
    name string
}

func (u User) Work() {
    fmt.Printf("Name : %s\n", u.name)
}

type People struct {
    name string
}

func (p *People) Work() {
    fmt.Printf("Name : %s\n", p.name)
}

func main() {
    var worker Worker

    u := User{name: "uuu"}
    worker = u  // valid
    worker = &u // valid
    worker.Work()

    p := People{name: "pppp"}
    // worker = p  // invalid
    worker = &p // valid
    worker.Work()
}
```