# How to understand pointer defined in function

Tags: go

I don't understand the following function definition.  what's the meaning of u *Unit in this function definition? I don't think it is returned value, cannot find the answer in Go tutorial.

```
func (u *Unit) processImage(){

 ....
}
```

Comment: It is the receiver of the method. processImage is a method defined for the type Unit. For a variable `u` of type Unit, you can call u.processImage(). processImage gets a pointer to `u`.

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/methods/4

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go (link above) for simple questions about Go syntax.

Answer (score -1):

In "func (u *Unit) processImage()" function, "u *Unit" is parameter/input and also receiver, it's depend what contains in processImage().
For example:

```
func (u *Unit) processImage() {
 u.sum = u.x + u.y
}
```

In this case processImage() used values of x and y fields of struct "Unit" as parameters/input to update value of "sum" and then return u (with new value of sum).
A method with (u *Unit) was called Pointer receivers.

A method like below with (u Unit) was called value receivers:

```
func (u Unit) processImage() int {
   return u.x + u.y
}
```

In value receivers, u contains parameter/input values, it's not a receiver.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expected for an answer, but if you want to know diff between Value receiver vs. pointer receiver you can refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775376/value-receiver-vs-pointer-receiver

Comment: Thanks all for answering the question. It really helps me learning go language.