# Why is the receiver value nil in this use of UnmarshalJSON()?

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I want to unmarshal some JSON, part of which contains a field of type `Spaces` defined as `type Spaces map[rune]float32`. In an attempt to make this work, I implemented `UnmarshalJSON([]byte) error` for said type to first leniently unmarshal into a `map[string]float32`, then only accept those key/value pairs where the key is exactly 1 rune in length.

However, when `UnmarshalJSON()` of the `Spaces` type is called, the receiver `s` is nil. Why?

```golang
type FontLoadInfo struct {
    FontMetrics
    Atlases []*AtlasLoadInfo
}

type FontMetrics struct {
    BaseKerning        float32
    KerningOffsets     map[string]float32
    Spaces             Spaces
    LineBreakYDistance float32
}

type AtlasLoadInfo struct {
    TextureFilePath          string
    BaseLineY                int
    HeightAboveBaseLine      int
    HeightBelowBaseLine      int
    DistanceBetweenBaseLines int
    MinBlankPixelColumns     int
    Lines                    []string
}

type Spaces map[rune]float32

func (s Spaces) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    if string(b) == "null" {
        return nil
    }
    var compliantMap map[string]float32
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &compliantMap)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for k, v := range compliantMap {
        if utf8.RuneCountInString(k) != 1 {
            return fmt.Errorf("none or multiple runes in key")
        }
        r, _ := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(k)
        if r == utf8.RuneError {
            return fmt.Errorf("invalid encoding in key")
        }
        s[r] = v // s is nil
    }
    return nil
}
```

Function for unmarshalling:

```golang
func ReadFontLoadInfo(filePath string) (*FontLoadInfo, error) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not read font load info file: %w", err)
    }
    var fontLoadInfo *FontLoadInfo
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &fontLoadInfo)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not unmarshal font load info: %w", err)
    }
    return fontLoadInfo, nil
}
```

The JSON I am trying to unmarshal:

```
{
    "Atlases": [
        {
            "TextureFilePath": "default-font-1.png",
            "BaseLineY": 130,
            "HeightAboveBaseLine": 80,
            "HeightBelowBaseLine": 24,
            "DistanceBetweenBaseLines": 117,
            "MinBlankPixelColumns": 10,
            "Lines": [
                "abcdefghijklm", "nopqrstuvwxyz",
                "ABCDEFGHIJKLM", "NOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
                "0123456789=?´`'",
                "!\"§$%&/()[]{}<>|",
                "*~+-_.,:;\\@€#²³",
                "äöüÄÖÜß"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "BaseKerning": 0.05,
    "Spaces": {
        " ": 0.2
    },
    "LineBreakYDistance": 1.1,
    "KerningOffsets": {
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a pointer receiver and create the map yourself.

Comment: "The receiver s is nil. Why?" Because nil is the zero value for a map, and you haven't initialized the map.

Comment: This bit of decode.go had me confused: `To unmarshal a JSON object into a map, Unmarshal first establishes a map to use. If the map is nil, Unmarshal allocates a new map.` This only applies to the root value plugged into `json.Unmarshal()`.

Comment: Also (unrelated to the question), fontLoadInfo is a pointer to FontLoadInfo, so you are unmarshaling into a pointer to a pointer. Don't do that. Either initialize fontLoadInfo with `new(FontLoadInfo)`, or change the type to `FontLoadInfo` (a non-pointer type).

Comment: @Peter Any particular reason for that? This appears to be perfectly supported by the `json` package.

Comment: I am not even sure myself anymore. This may be some sort of cargo cult thing on my side. Originally, I might have preferred pointer to pointer because your solution makes it apparent that fields are written twice (zero initialization plus unmarshalling) which is something subject to more rigorous optimization in languages which allow for it. (e.g. C) I acknowledge that kind of thinking makes no sense here.