# Can we use Type Assertion with interface method in Go?

Tags: go

I am trying to type assert in Go but error says struct doesn't implement interface method but I have clearly implemented method declared in interface.

This is the code I am trying to execute

```
package interfaces

import "fmt"

type Event interface {
    Accept()
}

type Like struct {
}

// Like implement Accept method from Event interface
func (l *Like) Accept() {
  fmt.Println("like accept")
}

func TypeAssertionExample() {
 var l *Like = &Like{}
 var e Event = l
 _, f := e.(Like) // error even after Like implemented Accept method 
 fmt.Println(f)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in addition to what [Hymns for Disco suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67815013/1256452), we can modify your example (I've changed it to `package main` and `func main` for use on the Go Playground) so that instead of:

```
func (l *Like) Accept) {
    // code
}
```

we have:

```
func (l Like) Accept() {
    // code
}
```

and the code will then compile.  But since `e` holds an instance of `*Like`, not one of `Like`, the test:

```
_, f := e.(Like)
fmt.Println(f)
```

prints `false` now.  [See the complete example here](https://play.golang.org/p/rac4Cp3sLDc).

The question of when and whether to use pointer receivers is quite a basic one, and covered fairly well, though not explicitly, in the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/).  [The FAQ has the same information in a more compact form](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers), with some [explicit details in a second section](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers).  See also [Value receiver vs. pointer receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27775376/1256452).

Answer (score 1):

Pointer types and non-pointer types aren't the same. You need to do this:

```golang
_, f := e.(*Like)
```

Notice the `*`, matching your variable declaration `var l *Like`.