# Confused about the official tour of Go's suggestion on using the same type of receiver for all methods

Tags: go

I'm trying to learn Go by going through the official Tour of Go, and I find the last part of [the section on value vs pointer receivers](https://go.dev/tour/methods/8) confusing:

*In general, all methods on a given type should have either value or pointer receivers, but not a mixture of both. (We'll see why over the next few pages.)*

Basically, I have two questions:

A) I can't seem to find the reason why we should not mix both types of receivers in the rest of the chapter, so if anyone could explain or reference the section that discusses this I would appreciate it.

B) Assuming that using a mixture of pointer and value receivers is indeed a bad idea, how would one go about implementing different interfaces? For example, I find that the tour describes two different builtin interfaces namely `Stringer` and `error`. In the provided code for `Stringer`, [a value receiver is used](https://go.dev/tour/methods/17) and switching to pointer receiver doesn't seem to work, whereas in the `error` interface, [a pointer receiver is used](https://go.dev/tour/methods/19). How would one go about implementing these two interfaces for a struct without violating the mentioned principle.

Note that I've already looked at similar questions about the drawbacks of using value receivers vs pointer receivers such as object creation, as well as the importance of having consistency (from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775376/value-receiver-vs-pointer-receiver)), but since I'm a real beginner to Go, I'm trying to contextualize these only with regards to the information/examples in the official Tour of Go.

Thanks!

Comment: Switching to a pointer receiver always can satisfy the same interface that a value receiver could. Interfaces are satisfied by the method set, see the spec for what that means: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_sets

Comment: To follow this principle when implementing the two interfaces on a type, consistently use either a pointer receiver or a value receiver for all methods.  For example use `func (v MyType) Error() string { ... }; func (v MyType) String() string { ... }` OR `func (v *MyType) Error() string { ... }; func (v *MyType) String() string { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question, having both value and pointer receivers can cause subtle races, because a value receiver copies the object. For instance:

```
type T struct {
  field int
}

func (T) ValueReceiver() int {return 1}

func (t *T) SetField(i int) {t.field=i}
```

In the example above, if you call `SetField` and `ValueReceiver` concurrently, you have a race. This is because while `SetField` is writing to the field, the `ValueReceiver` is creating a copy of the receiver, resulting in a read of the same field without any explicit synchronization.

For the second question: If you have methods modifying `T`, it makes sense to make all methods use a pointer receiver. That way you can prevent subtle races, and implement all interfaces `T` would.

This is the link to the FAQ about this subject (thanks to @jub0bs):

https://go.dev/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers

This example is based on the following post:

https://dave.cheney.net/2015/11/18/wednesday-pop-quiz-spot-the-race

Comment: All other things being equal, you would have a synchronisation bug even if both methods used a pointer receiver.

Comment: @jub0bs, no. The `ValueReceiver` does not explicitly read the `field`.

Comment: Perhaps, but this is a very contrived example, and not the general reason why mixing value and pointer receivers is discouraged.

Comment: @jub0bs what is the general reason why it is discouraged?

Comment: Consistency simply makes the type easier to use; the FAQ has [a section about this](https://go.dev/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers).

Comment: @jub0bs, thanks for the link, I added that to the answer.

Comment: I still think that mixing value methods and pointer methods is a bad idea even in a sequential setting, but I've since come across https://dave.cheney.net/2015/11/18/wednesday-pop-quiz-spot-the-race and I have a newfound appreciation for your example. Sorry for dismissing it a bit too quickly.

Comment: @jub0bs, thanks for that link. My example was actually based on that post, but I couldn't find it when I wrote the answer.